# Make the rows of the datagrid draggable in GWT

Tags: gwt, datagrid, drag-and-drop, draggable, celltable

I want to make a datagrid in which rows will be draggable so that a person can move rows up and down by dragging the rows. As row of the datagrid will be get as an element. I know how to make the widgets draggable, but how the rows of the datagrid can be made draggable?
I don't want to use any extra plugin or library for achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

The only library I know of that support drag&drop with(in) cell widgets is [GwtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) with [droppable](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers#The_cell_widgets) plugin, see their [showcase](http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/branches/droppable_1_0/demo/CellTableSample/CellTableSample.html). I suggest your to give it a try instead reinventing the wheel (or take inspiration from their codebase). See this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gwtquery/GYPFyvE4ttU/discussion) about your `CellTable` use case.

Comment: buddy i do not want to use the third party library for implementing it.